# PHP require() of an image occasionally returns invalid/truncated image

Tags: php, image, apache

I wrote a quick PHP script for loading an image in a directory, but I've been finding that it regularly gives me "Image truncated or corrupt" errors in the Error Console, despite the images not being corrupt. I'm able to view the image normally if I browse to its full path, and I'm also able to download it and view it without issue. I've tried using different browsers but have the same problem.

Oddly enough, some images work fine and some do not. The issue doesn't seem to be related to file size.

My code is pretty simple, and I've been using it for ages:

```
if (isset($_GET['i']) && is_numeric($_GET['i'])) {
$path = 'D:/Images/';
if (is_file($path . $i . '.jpg')) {
   header('content-type: image/jpg');
   require($path . $i . '.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using require, that includes the image as if it were PHP code. You should be using [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile), which will just open the image and send it straight to the browser:

```
readfile($path . $i . '.jpg');
exit;
```

Also note that you'll want to call `exit()` after `readfile()`.